# Saving object from ListView in django

Tags: django

I have a generic ListView which displays all objects from a model and I would like users to be able to choose one object for further processing by storing in session or in another model. What would be the best way to go about this?

views.py

```
class TranscriptListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Transcript
    template_name = 'transcript_list.html'
```

template

```
{% block content %}
<ul>
    {% for transcript in transcript_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ transcript.get_absolute_url }}">{{transcript.name}}</a>
        <p>{{transcript.text}}</p>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting something to store in a session, I'd just do a

```
class SelectTranscriptView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
    model = Transcript

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = self.get_object()
        request.session['selected_transcript'] = object.id
        return redirect(...)
```

This view only accepts POST, since GET requests should be idempotent, i.e. they should not modify any state. Setting a session value is definitely modifying state. This means you'll need to use a form (or a JavaScript function) to POST data to the URL you hook this up to.

**More importantly, though:** Setting something in the session is not necessarily a good idea at all. Consider an advanced user deciding to open multiple tabs to your site, and trying to select one transcript for one tab, and another in the other tab. This won't be possible if you store the selected thing in the session! Instead, I'd design things so the ID of the object being edited or viewed is always in the URL (as happens with DetailViews and the ilk anyway).